# JasperReports - Defining a parameter of a custom class

Tags: java, parameters, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have a jar file containing a Bean class and integrated it already to the Jasper project like this:

[image]

I can see this class when I try to set a type for a parameter like:

[image]

I have also imported the package containing the parameter type class into the report as follows:

[image]

However, I'm still getting the following compilation error:

[image]

What am I missing? Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing it right, jasper soft studio is just messy with these imported libs, try the answers on the dupe.